# Identify the frequency spectrum of an audio file by using matlab

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency, spectrum-estimation

I need to identify the first few harmonics of a audio file by cancelling the noise of the specific signal.
So I have partitioned the signal into 1024 Hz sample blocks and then took the FFT values of each block separately and finally add all FFT values and plot the waveform. Here is my matlab code. Somebody help me with the code since i cannot add the first block fft into total fft. Get an error. Please somebody help me

```
clc
clear
[signal,fs] =audioread('Female_55.wav'); %Only for plotting 
t=0:1/fs:(length(signal)-1)/fs;          %Only for plotting

fs0=fs/1024                        %number of frequency blocks
t1=length(signal)/fs;              %length of the waveform

s=1;    %starting value
s1=1;   %ending value
c1=1;

wavefft_tot= zeros(1025,1);

for blocks = 1:fs0  

[signal1,fs1] =audioread('Female_55.wav',[s*c1 s1*1024]);
wavefft_next=abs(fft(signal1));
wavefft_prv=wavefft_next;

n=length(signal1)-1;  %plotting information
f=0:fs1/n:fs1;        %plotting information

if(s==1) && (c1==1)
    c1=1;
    s=1024;
    s1=s1+1; 
    wavefft_tot= wavefft_next; 
else
   s1=s1+1;
   c1=c1+1;  
   wavefft_tot=wavefft_tot+wavefft_prv;

    end

    end 

    figure(1);
    plot(f,wavefft_tot);
    xlabel('Frequency in Hz');
    ylabel('Magnitude');
    title('The Wave FFT');
```

Comment: "get an error" indicates this is not a signal processing question, but a programming question. thus, this question is off-topic here, but might be on-topic on stackoverflow.com. However, there it'll be closed, too, because "get an error" is not a problem description. Quite obviously, the **verbatim** error is relevant to your problem; properly indent your code, too, that might already help you solve your problem yourself.

Comment: What error are you getting? Note also the FT is invariant in magnitude only under a time shift but not phase, to properly combine you would want to compensate for linear phase shift in each subgroup.  Otherwise if you are only concerned with magnitude, you would benefit by taking the absolute value before combining to eliminate the possible cancellations due to phase rotation.

Comment: Also if it matters there will be a small error in your frequency axis I believe; the FT goes from 0 to 1 sample less than Fs, where your range is 0 to Fs (although correct number of points). If n is large the error will likely be insignificant.

Comment: @DanBoschen Actually hope you get an idea about the code. just stick into for loop. simply inside the for loop first iteration it does is take first block of the signal and convert it into  FFT. actually that fft value going to store it in wavefft_prv and wavefft_next.

Comment: So what is the error or what do you think is wrong with what you are doing? (I do see now that you are taking the absolute value) ,but don't see the point of assigning wavefft_prv ?

Comment: "Error using + Matrix dimensions must agree" this what i get. Im using wavefft_next variable to store fft value at each new iteration. wavefft_prev variable using only for add that value into wavefft_tot variable. At the end of the for loop i needed to display wavefft_tot

Comment: Actually if i comment the, wavefft_tot= wavefft_next; my code is perfectly works. But in there only it will add first block of fft into wavefft_tot

Comment: Simpy inside the if condition, wavefft_prv=wavefft_next; it will change the dimension of the matrix. Thats why i cannot add it into wavefft_tot variable

Comment: @DanBoschen just try my code in the matlab by giving any audio file

Comment: @UmeshWickramasuriya I won't run your code, but I do see that you are using a length 1025 vector for wavefft_tot= zeros(1025,1); but you said that you are processing 1024 length fft's. That's likely why your dimensions don't agree. Otherwise if they are both the same length double check that one does not need to be trasposed (is 1024x1 and the other is 1x1024). I think the first is your issue.   As Marcus has pointed out, your question is more of a coding question and not a signal processing one, so doesn't really belong here (in case you see it gets removed). In any event, hope I helped.

Comment: @DanBoschen Nope i intentionally put wavefft_tot= zeros(1025,1); because wavefft_next and wavefft_prev both variables create size of (1025,1). Only problem inside the if condition, wavefft_tot= wavefft_next; wavefft_tot create (1024,1) matrix

Comment: Is the audioread function returning 1024 length blocks for subsequent reads based on the way you are indexing? (So first block is 1025 and next ones are 1024)? If you haven't used single step debugging yet that would help you in this case, and just single step through your code to see where the variable size is changing.

Comment: @DanBoschen Actually this what i needed. I have an audio signal. i needed to check the spectrum of the signal. Rather than sending the whole signal and convert it into fft by doing this way i can cancel noise. Im not good at matlab.

Comment: @DanBoschen Just help me to write a code

Comment: This isn't a code writing site. I don't think anyone here would do that but we're willing to help you with any questions you have related to signal processing. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to recreate the functionality in [spectrogram](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html). Spectrogram will give you a short-time Fourier transform using whatever blocksize you specify.

Much of your code looks like it is re-inventing this.

Comment: "Error using  + Matrix dimensions must agree"  Actually hope you get an idea about the code. just stick into for loop. simply inside the for loop first iteration it does is take first block of the signal and convert it into  FFT. actually that fft value going to store it in wavefft_prv and wavefft_next. As you can see there's a IF condition. simply that condition works only for first block. Iikewise all the blocks going to calculate fft at each iterations and save it in the wavefft_tot.

Comment: Please somebody help me to write a matlab code